# How to add another dictionary entry in a nested python dictionary

Tags: python, django

I would like to make a dictionary in the dictionary.

I have this code

```
 dictionary = {}
    for g in genre:
        total = 0
        products = Product.objects.filter(genre=g)
        for product in products:
            total += product.popularity
        dictionary[g.category] = {g.name: total}
```

I would like it to look like this, for example

{'book': {'Horror':0, 'Comedy:0}, 'cd': {'Disco': 0, 'Rap': 0}}

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In order to get help, you will need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Is g.category typically 'book' or 'cd'?

Comment: It should work fine like this. Is this code throwing any error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `defaultdict` to store the values.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
dictionary = defaultdict(dict)
# update it:
dictionary[g.category][g.name] = total;
# or
dictionary[g.category] |= {g.name: total}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think everything looks good. I bet the issue you are having is this line `dictionary[g.category] = {g.name: total}`. This will writing over top of any previous entries. Add another line to append.

```
sub_dict = dictionary[g.category] 
sub_dict[g.name] =  total
```

This should append to the sub dictionary instead.

Answer (score 0):

for g in genre:
total = 0
products = Product.objects.filter(genre=g)
for product in products:
total += product.popularity
if g.category not in dictionary:
dictionary[g.category] = {}
dictionary[g.category][g.name] = total